# Quotes within quotes breaking

Tags: punctuation, syntax, nesting, markup

When a word in single quotes falls at the end of the quotation, LaTeX decides to render it as "' instead of '". For example:

```
``He said it was `off the hook'''
```

would render: "He said it was 'off the hook"' (I don't know if the font will make that noticeable or not). Any workarounds?

Moreover, there is no difference between `'{}''` and `''{}'`, so I'm starting to suspect a package conflict or something.

For reference, my header is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{csquotes} % This worked, but can it be done without loading a package?
%\enquote{He said it was \enquote{off the hook}} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: ``'\,''`` is the usual trick. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Is there a way to render it without the space?

Comment: That renders backwards again (regardless of `'{}''` or `''{}'`).

Comment: Remove `inputenc` as soon as possible. I can't reproduce the issue, as I get the same output as I showed in the picture linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: Alright, but that doesn't seem to fix my problem. This is very bizarre. As soon as I switch over to `csquotes` it fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the csquotes package!
It also offers great possibilieties to cope with the different quoting styles of the various languages (babel and polyglossia are supported)

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{german}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Deja Vu Sans}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\enquote{He said it was \enquote{off the hook}}

\textgerman{\enquote{Er sagte, er wäre \enquote{aus dem Schneider}}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: This gives me a space between the quotes, which I don't want because of the font I'm using.

Comment: Why should you not want a space because of the font? I just had look, and with DejaVu Sans, the space definetly should be there.

Comment: Can't say much more than 'taste'. It's perfectly noticeable to me.

Comment: to cite Jost Hochulli: "Good, comfortable legibility is not a matter of personal taste". Think of the space as disambiguisation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for dealing with consecutive quotes is separating them with a thin space:

```
``He said it was `off the hook'\,''
```

Here's a sample, where various inputs are compared:

````
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Input & Rendering \\
\verb|``He said it was `off the hook'''| & ``He said it was `off the hook''' \\
\verb|``He said it was `off the hook'\,''| & ``He said it was `off the hook'\,'' \\
\verb|``He said it was `off the hook'{}''| & ``He said it was `off the hook'{}'' \\
\verb|```| & ``` \\
\verb|``{}`| & ``{}` \\
\verb|``\,`| & ``\,` \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
````

[image]

With the first input, the order is wrong; with the third input there is no way for the user to distinguish the quotes.

If the font already puts spaces between single and double quotes, then you have just to hide the first ligature (third form): `'{}''`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
``He said it was `off the hook'{}''
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use direct input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
“He said it was ‘off the hook’”   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `inputenc` should never be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Note also that calling first `fullpage` and then `geometry` is a waste, as the latter overrides the settings made by the former package. Neither package can influence the typesetting, as they just set the page parameters.

Comment: I prefer the third option because the font I'm using makes it distinguishable. However, when I do `'{}''` it renders as though it were `''{}'`.

Comment: @JoeyGarlic Are you sure? What font is it?

Comment: DejaVu Sans (using fontspec). The double-quotes are distinctly separate from the single-quotes. And I'm sure.

Comment: @JoeyGarlic I added `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}`; then compiled with XeLaTeX and the result of the third form is like in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYMi6.png) Please, add more information to your question.

Comment: I added my header to the question. If anything I suspect it's a package conflict, since it's at the very beginning of my document.

Comment: @JoeyGarlic Sorry, but I can't reproduce what you say you get.

Comment: That's a shame. I'll just load `csquotes` then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: With `csquotes` I get extended space between the quotes.